# How many 6-digit numbers have distinct digits and the sum of their digits is a multiple of 9.

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

How many 6-digit numbers have distinct digits and the sum of their digits is a multiple of 9.

My attempt :

Our gf:

$f(x)=(1+y)(1+xy)(1+x^{2}y+...+(1+x^9y)$

I don't know how can I continue after that.

I've never solved a multivariable generating function before.

Could you help me for solving completely this problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that no matter what the least five digits are, there's a unique choice for the leading digit that makes the sum a multiple of $9$ (trusting that the leading digit is not allowed to be $0$).

Comment: @lulu the issue is, the unique choice for the leading digit may be one of the $5$ already included, so the answer $\frac{10!}{5!} = 30240$ is an overcount.

Comment: @FredT  Absolutely, I somehow missed the condition the the digits were distinct.

Comment: I expect it helps to notice that the sum of all $10$ digits is divisible by $9$ so looking for six of them that sum to a multiple of $9$ is the same as looking for four that sum to a multiple of $9$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method for solving the problem in the naive/brute force way.

**Edit: this list is wrong, see comments**

I believe the following give the only sets of 6 distinct digits which add to a multiple of 9:

- $\{0,1,2,3,4,8\}$
- $\{1,2,3,4,8,9\}$
- $\{0,1,2,3,5,7\}$
- $\{1,2,3,5,7,9\}$
- $\{0,1,2,4,5,6\}$
- $\{1,2,4,5,6,9\}$
- $\{2,3,4,5,6,7\}$
- $\{1,3,4,5,6,8\}$
- $\{0,1,2,4,5,6\}$
- $\{1,2,4,5,6,9\}$

For each set of 6 digits: if $0$ is included, there are $5 \times 5! = 600$ possible orderings, since $0$ cannot be the first digit. If $0$ is not in the set, there are $6! =720$ ways to order the digits. Since $6$ of the sets don't contain $0$, and $4$ do contain $0$, the total number of ways is $6 \times 720 + 4 \times 600 = 6720$.

Comment: You included some sets twice.

Comment: There are also lots of sets missing, e.g. {1,2,4,5,7,8}, {0,3,4,5,7,8}, {1,2,3,6,7,8}, and about 10 others.

Comment: @Freshman'sDream d'oh, that's what I get for trying to do this while half asleep. Thank you for pointing it out, I've edited my answer to make it clear this isn't correct. Hopefully someone comes along with a better idea soon!